# Specifying a range of columns as parameter

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I want to extract the max value of a table that has 100 rows: Something that can be **poorly** achieved like this:

```
maxA = max(data['a1size'].max(), data['a2size'].max(), data['a3size'].max()... and continuing like this until a100size.
```

Of course that solution will be not ideal at all.

Is there a better approach and more elegant than using a `for` loop?

I'm looking for some kind of `..` operator. Something like:

```
maxA = max(data['a1size'].max() .. data['a100size'].max())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `loc` operator allows you to use slicing by column names:

```py
maxA = data.loc[:, 'a1size':'a100size'].values.max()
```

Note that in contrast to core Python slicing, the final column is included here. The first `:` specifies that you want all the rows.

This works if the columns you want to take the maximum over are contiguous. Otherwise, you could index the dataframe with a list of column names instead. To construct such a list, you could use a list comprehension:

```py
a_size_cols = [f'a{i}size' for i in range(1, 101)]

maxA = data[a_size_cols].values.max()
```

Comment: Thanks @Arne, this works great. The problem is that, as you mentioned, the columns are not contiguous. I have `a1size, b1size, a2size, b2size...` I will investigate how to index the dataframe with the column names. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Lisandro. I have added a way to do this for non-contiguous columns.

Comment: Thank you very much @Arne! Unfortunately I can't upvote yet. Your solution works fantastically. Very much appreciated!